# How to I use user value at Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgresql 9.6 version

I want to use an user value like "declare"

```
DECLARE @Val1 INT
SET @VAL1 = 123
SELECT @Var1 [INT]
```

But it's impossible to use the "Declare" definition at PostgreSQL.
How to I use an user value in simple?

Comment: I'm using it in a function in pg13 - 

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_something(varchar(128), boolean)
RETURNS TABLE ( xx name, yy text, curr_owner text, zz text) AS
$func$
  DECLARE
    var_1 ALIAS FOR $1;
    var_2 ALIAS FOR $2;
   BEGIN
```

Comment: What is a "user value"? Why is "declare" a value? Why is it not possible to use declared values in PostgreSQL? What does it mean to use anything in "simple"?